# After Installing the module H5P I got the message and white screen - The website encountered an error, please try again later

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

After installing the module H5P, my site wouldn't load and only displayed "Error" The website encountered an error, please try again later

I had to manually disable the H5P modules in the database then clear the cache and a few minutes later the website started loading again. It also seems as if sub-domains couldn't load during this time.

Has anyone else experienced this?

After uninstalling and deleting the H5P module, it still shows on the page: admin/config/system/h5p but when the H5P link is clicked I get a Website encountered an error, please try again later error.

I can't seem to clear the cache via the site admin and I can't save panel pages. It says saved but when i try to access the page url, it says page not found.

Someone else said "I've had the same or similar issue. When I install, I just get a WSOD. I ended up using the missing module cleaner to get my site back to working normal after manually uninstalling it."

I've installed the module missing fixer module and when I enabled the module I got a "Website encountered an error, please try again later error." message but when I refresh the page, it shows the module is enabled.

However, when I click on "configure" from the module list page, it takes me to /admin/config/system with no option to configure the settings or actually use the module.

Should I be looking in the database for something that could fix this issue?

Comment: Which D7  core version ? which php version ? did you follow steps for usage https://www.drupal.org/project/h5p ?

Comment: D7.65, PHP7.2 and I had H5P working on a subdomain without any issues. It was only when I tried to install it on the primary domain that I had the issues. I have exported the database of the site that has this issue and imported to a newly created database on a dev site and it works 100%, clear of the error. I'm not sure why though but that seems to work so far.

Comment: Maybe another module in conflict , search into incompatibility issues know for this case. Check schema into database if all is correct

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems that clearing ALL the cache tables was all that I needed to do. This should have been my 1st, most basic action but I only cleared the cache table and not all cache_* tables. Everything is back to normal without any errors

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by truncating every cache_ table in the database.